# RegEx: a group to match any string beginning with a specific character

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm creating some reports in Google Analytics. 
I am trying to write a RegEx that will match

www.website.com/

www.website.com/?_string_begins_with_question_mark

But will **not** match

www.website.com/string_doesnt_begin_with_question_mark

Using Reggy (with POSIX Extended), I tried to create an optional group that would match a string beginning with a question mark, followed by any number of characters. I thought

(\?.+)?

would do the trick, but it ignores the question mark requirement, and matches any string.

I tried some variations:

www.website.com/(\?(.+))?

www.website.com/(\?.+)?

www.website.com/(?.+)?

Et cetera.

Any help is appreciated - Sorry if this has already been asked! I'm new to RegEx.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regexp

```
www.website.com/(\?.+)?
```

will still match anything that contains `www.website.com/`, no matter what comes after the slash. Have you tried appending a `$` (end-of-input marker)?

```
www\.website\.com/(?:\?.+)?$
```

(Escape the dots for more precision; the `?:` is just a way of indicating that the group is of no special meaning and does not have to be remembered -- if you omit this, you can access the contents of the group by `\1`, e.g., in a replace operation.)

Comment: Thank you. I would have noticed this working, but I was using Reggy's multi-line feature wrong. Like a boss.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
www.website.com/\?(.+)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

```
www.website.com/($|\?.+$)
```

Either empty or question mark plus some string